# Getting the even entries using PHP

Tags: php, foreach

im trying to make a foreach loop that prints out the even lines in a variable
i have tried doing a code like this:

```
$admin = '1';

if ($admin = 0)
  {
    echo "even";
    $admin = '1';
    continue;
  }
if ($admin = 1)
  {
    echo "ODD";
    $admin = '0';
  }
```

but its always odd and never even.. im doing something wrong..

if any of you have an idea i would love to know what you think

if it would work only if $admin = 0 i would print the line of course and not "even"

Comment: You are assigning to the variable instead of comparing.

Comment: Use `if ($admin ==` instead of `if ($admin =`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong operator for checking. `=` is used for declaration while `==` must be used for valuating.

Try,

```
if($admin==0)
{
echo "Even";
}
```

While,

```
$admin=0 // sets the value 0 to the variable $admin
```

Comment: wow thanks man,solved it all! in 10 minutes i will make this the right answer

Answer (score 0):

`$admin = '1'` is the representation of the char.

In if statement you want to compare it to the integer.

Additionally you're assigning the value in if statement instead of comparing.

Try following code:

```
$admin = 1;

if ($admin == 0)
  {
    echo "even";
    $admin = 1;
    continue;
  }
if ($admin == 1)
  {
    echo "ODD";
    $admin = 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a simple typographical error, use `if ($admin == 0)` instead of `if ($admin = 0)`. `=` is the assignment operator, `==` is for comparison.

You could also use the modulus operator (`%`) in a for loop to check if the current row is even or odd:

```
$var = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($var); $i++) {
    echo $i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
    echo "\n";
}
```

You can read more about the modulus operator in the manual: [Arithmetic Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)